# Upgrading Apache and keeping PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, apache-2.4

I have `CentOS6.4` and currently running `PHP5.3` with mod_php and `Apache2.2`

I've been trying to find an easy way to upgrade to `Apache2.4`, but the only things I've found are for `php-fpm`

I'd like to keep the `mod_php` if possible.

Does anyone have any resources or rpm/repos that will enable Apache2.4 with mod_php

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use any of the container implementation to get what you want.
Or use your own repository with custom packages.
Or install the software needed in custom prefix.

Comment: I've been looking into using the `ius` repos. But it doesn't seem to like `PHP5.3` with `Apache2.4`